# werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint python flask

Tags: routes, endpoint, internals

I'm trying to create login page and register page for personal project in Python / Flask but I am facing this error in vscode terminal, when I try to access Register endpoint:

> "werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'Register'. Did you mean 'register' instead?

Here in the code only the hello page works, if I include /register or /login in endpoint it throws:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

app.py

```
import mailbox
from flask import Flask,url_for,request, render_template,redirect
import os
import psycopg2
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_mail import Message


app = Flask(__name__)

connection = psycopg2.connect(
            database="***",user="***",password="*****",host="localhost",port=5432
           )
cursor = connection.cursor()    

@app.route('/hello',methods=["GET","POST"])
def hello():
    if(request.method =="GET" or request.method == "POST"):
        postgre_str="select * from play.player_list"
        cursor.execute(postgre_str)
        player_records = cursor.fetchall()
    
    if     (request.method == "POST"):
        player_name=request.form.get("playername")
    
        postgre_str="insert into play.player_list(player_name) values('{0}')".format(player_name)
         cursor.execute(postgre_str)
    
        connection.commit()
     cursor.close()
     connection.close()
    return render_template('index.html',player_records=player_records)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
     if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' or request.form['password'] != 'admin':
             error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('hello'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)

@app.route('/register', methods=['POST','GET'])
def register():
    # Perform any necessary actions here
    # mail = mailbox(app)
    return render_template('register.html',status='ok')
    # return redirect(url_for('register',status='ok'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

login.html:

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Play Soccer - login page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="static/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
       </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <h1>Please login</h1>
          <br>
          <form action="/hello" method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">
             <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
            <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="hello">
          </form>
           {% if error %}
            <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}
          {% endif %}


    <a href="{{url_for('Register')}}">Register</a>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

index.html:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>GIF Display Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>GIF Display Example</h1>
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='image.gif') }}" alt="image.gif" width="1200"                  height="500">
    <form method='POST' action="{{url_for("hello")}}">
        <label for="fname">player choice </label><br>
        <p>
            <select id="playername" name="playername">

            {%for i in player_records %}
            <option  value={{i[0]}}>{{i[1]}}</option>
            {%endfor%}
            </select>
        </p>
        <button type="submit">enter</button>
    </form>
     <form method='POST' action="">
        <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br>
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label><br>
        <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Register.html

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Play Soccer - register page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="static/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Register</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="/register.html">
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
          <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">

        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change in your "Register.html" this:
{{url_for('Register')}}
to this
{{url_for('register')}}

to match the naming in your function definition to the call for that function.

Or change the name in your py code to uppercase:

@app.route('/register', methods=['POST','GET'])
def **R**egister():